# Only load a plugin when +python is enabled

Tags: vim

I have a plugin that will only run if vim has been compiled with +python [pythonhelper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=435). I share my .vim with a number of machines, and some of the machines don't have vim compiled with python mode turned on.

So, I would want to know: is there a vim command I can put in my vimrc so I can conditionally include the plugin?

Something like:

```
if PYTHON_FEATURE_ENABLED
    add the pythonhelper to the runtimepath...
end
```

I know I can modify vim's runtimepath to include the plugin, but what's the vim syntax to do this kind of condition in .vimrc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if has("python")
 " code here
endif
```